# How do I get the value of a dynamic select field from another select field in React JS

Tags: reactjs, select

https://codepen.io/abhilashn/pen/zYrEbyx

Above is my codepen where I select different state but I am not able set the first value of district on change

```
changeState(e) {
var state;
 if(e.target.name == "state") {
   state = e.target.value
    this.setState({ defaultState: state, defaultDistrict: '' });
  }
  else if(e.target.name == "district"){
    this.setState({ defaultState: this.state.defaultState, defaultDistrict: e.target.value })
  }
  else {
    this.setState({ defaultState: this.state.defaultState,
      defaultDistrict: this.state.defaultDistrict
    })
  }

this.getDataFromApi();
```

}

When I change the state i should immediately get the first option of district as defaultDistrict but I am setting it to ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in two ways,

- You can store the entire `state_district_wise` API response in component state. And get the districts info from that object based on the selected state from the dropdown and set the first district value as `defaultDistrict`
- Another way in your `getDataFromApi` method once you fetch the response from API while updating the districts along with other data in the component state you can also update the `defaultDistrict` like below

```
this.setState({
   districts: dists,
   districtsData: dData,
   districtConfirmedCases: confirmedCases,
   districtActiveCases: activeCases,
   districtDeceasedCases: deceasedCases,
   districtRecoveredCases: recoveredCases,
   confirmedCases: districtsConfirmedCases,
   confirmedBgColor: districtsConfirmedBgColor,
   activeCases: districtsActiveCases,
   activeBgColor: districtsActiveBgColor,
   deceasedCases: districtsDeceasedCases,
   deceasedBgColor: districtsDeceasedBgColor,
   recoveredCases: districtsRecoveredCases,
   recoveredBgColor: districtsRecoveredBgColor,
   ...(!dists.includes(this.state.defaultDistrict) && {
      defaultDistrict: dists[0]
   })
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks your solution helped me a bit.

Comment: I'm happy to have helped you :)